Largest Elliptic Cone Intersecting with Sphere
I have a function that can be reasonably approximated with an elliptic cone with a certain excentricity I can calculate, I have the dimensions of the axes so for example a = 1 and b = 0.25.
I then also have a sphere somewhere outside of the cone (I know it's outside by construction), we can assume that the elliptic cone is centered at the origin, axis is aligned up and the minor and major axes are aligned too, I'd convert the sphere to the local coordinate system of the cone as necessary.
The elliptic cone can be inflated uniformly by a factor s until it touches the sphere at a single point. I have a shadertoy that illustrates this interactively and the point I'm interested in (that I calculate via the original function) is close to this point that I see visually. The question then is, how would I go about finding the scaling factor and (more importantly) the point at which it touches?
It's a problem I'm trying to solve for 3D graphics, I would later try to extend this to a disk and a plane but I'd like to start solving this at least. I've been looking at ellipse and cone math for a few days now and it seems a lot less intuitive and complicated in my head than I thought it would be.
Many thanks for any light you could shed on the problem.

If you don't know the length of the axes for some value of $s$, then there is no way to find them AND $s$.

For argument's sake say that for an s = 1 (default scale), a = 1 and b = 0.25, and the sphere is known to be outside of it. As in, I have computed an elliptic cone via other means, and I want to know which scaled version of that touches the sphere once
I have clarified the question
